# Execution python-paramiko

Tags: python, paramiko

I am trying to execute some command to remote machine through python

```
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(SERVER_IP, username='root', password='xxxxx')
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(
        "tar -C /home -xzf /home/Tests.tar.gz;dos2unix /home/Tests/run.py;chmod +x /home/Tests/run.py;/home/Tests/run.py>/home/Tests/log.txt"
    )
```

it seems the last command `/home/Tests/run.py>/home/Tests/log.txt` is not working the `log.txt` is not having the values, the same works well if I do `/home/Tests/run.py>/home/Tests/log.txt` on remote machine terminal.

How to resolve it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are not transporting the client to session like so :

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(SERVER_IP, username='root', password='xxxxx')
#note the next line you are missing
ssh_session = ssh.get_transport().open_session()
```

Then (after the declaration of ssh_session) you may use `ssh_session.exec_command(. . .)`.

Try that see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure your `paramiko` code is working and the connection is being made, try something simple like

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("hostname")
```

and make sure that `stdin` contains what you expect. Then have a go at debugging the command you're executing remotely:

```
$ tar -C /home -xzf /home/Tests.tar.gz
$ dos2unix /home/Tests/run.py
$ chmod +x /home/Tests/run.py
$ /home/Tests/run.py > /home/Tests/log.txt
```

If you run code on the remove machine through a regular `ssh` connection it must perform as you expect it to if you want it to also work over `paramiko`.